# .htaccess - point primary to subfolder and remove it + rewrite for "pretty urls"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble getting this to work without seeing my sub-directory in the URL...

```
# This is in root directory
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
Rewriterule ^(?!abc/)(.*)$ /abc/$1 [L,NC]
```

and

```
# This is in sub-directory

RewriteBase /pages/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=pages/(.+?)\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R,L]

RewriteBase /pages/    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php?url=pages/$0.php [L]
```

The problem is, to make this work I have to have my `base` url set to "mysite.com/abc/content" instead of just "mysite.com/content". **I'm pretty sure the answer is that *I can't have my cake and eat it too*** (due to the nature of the redirects), but wanted to check before I move this site back to the server root.

*It looks so nice and organized having it in **one** folder like the other sites on my server :(*

Example

```
-public_html
  --site1
  --site2
  --site3
  --abc
```

My host is set up to look in public_html for the primary domain. There is no way to change this except for redirect in the public_html via `.htaccess`.

If I redirect to the sub-folder (`/abc/`), then I have to make my `base` href `mysite.com/abc/`. This is undesirable. I want my `<base>` to work with `mysite.com/`, and the sub-folder to never be visible in the URLs.

It seems this is impossible with the way it's set up. I just took the primary site's contents and dropped them into public_html for now - but it's ugly.

Comment: I cannot understand what exactly is the question you're asking. Can you clarify with few examples.

Comment: Essentially how to redirect to a sub-folder without having to change the `<base href="">`. Updated question to try to better reflect this.

Comment: So this is just for loading css/js/images that you had to use `<base href="/abc/">`?

Comment: Links too. Everything with a relative URL was affected, without changing the base like so everything was broken. Removing `/abc/` makes the rewrite pointless, as it goes back to looking for the files in the root directory (I assume). Any other site, the host does something (I assume in httpd.conf) to make it happen without .htaccess - they will not for the primary.

Comment: Why do you need this for links since rewrite rule is already prefixing `/abc/` before all the URLs.

Comment: `/abc/` shows up. It looks bad. I want `mysite.com/home`, not `mysite.com/abc/home`. Maybe I'm messing something up in the rewrites, but changing the `base` was the only way I could get anything but text to load. Tried several different ways.

Comment: But how is `/abc/` showing up in URL if you're just doing internal rewrite? Do you have `/abc/.htaccess` file as well?

Comment: Yes, one is in the root, one in `/abc/`. The one in `/abc/` is the 2nd gray box - it cleans up/removes the query string and `index.php`. It is possible I had it working but the way I call my content was causing it to fail. Are you saying the above code *should* work as is?

Comment: Yes comment out `[R,L]` rule and take out `<base>` tag and then test in a new browser.